# Big Oh notation calculation

Tags: computer-science

Prove T(n)=n^2 -10n +33  is O(n^2)  by finding the smallest n0 and c>0.

My solution to this problem is;

```
 T(n)=n^2 -10n +33 given
    <= n^2  if n>= 4
    <=1*n2  if n>=4
    c=1 and n=4
```

however my instructor told me this is wrong, I can not easily remove -10n+33

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming. It may be a better fit for cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score -1):

Following my knowledge you can ignore the fact of having -10n+33 in that case because n^2 will grow up much more quickly than -10n-33, which you can ignore for most cases, but your teacher maybe is talking about some kind of aproximations that i heard about too (i am not a specialist in that aproximations btw).

Hope this helps you.